# Can you operate a JS function within an array?

Tags: javascript

I have JS quiz where the questions are picked from an array in a random order. I'm trying to replace each question with an image (the club crest) but keep the answer format in place.  Is this possible and how?

Current code is as follows:

JavaScript

```
const questions = [
    {
        question:  `What league do Manchester United play in?`,
        answers: [
            {text: 'Premier League', correct: true},
            {text: 'Championship', correct: false},
            {text: 'League One', correct: false},
            {text: 'Scottish Premiership', correct: false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'What league do Millwall play in?',
        answers: [
            {text: 'Premier League', correct: false},
            {text: 'Championship', correct: true},
            {text: 'League One', correct: false},
            {text: 'Scottish Premiership', correct: false}
        ]
    },
```

HTML:

```
<div id="question"><img id="crest" src="assets/images/image1.png"></div>
```

I've created these functions in JS but don't know how to get them operated inside the question

```
function displayManutdCrest() {
    document.getElementById('crest').src='assets/images/image2.png'
}
```

```
function displayMillwallCrest() {
    document.getElementById('crest').src='assets/images/image3.png'
}
```

I'm only just learning JS so apologies if this makes no sense

Comment: Why is there a function for each question? Don't you think this might be a problem in the future when there are more/different questions?

Comment: The easiest way would be to store the link of the image in your `questions` array, next to its question and answer.

Comment: If you have a way of matching the image up with the question or answer, then yes, it's possible

Comment: Andreas - It was the only way I could think of really and even then I didn't think it would work lol.

Comment: BNilsou and TKoL - how would I do that?

Comment: Thanks for reading and responding by the way :)

Comment: What does the code that uses the `questions` array look like? As someone mentioned above, if you just store the url to the image, and have a function that takes a `src` parameter and sets the image's `src`, you will only need one function to cover all of the crests rather than one each.

Comment: @JamesEvans however you want. Unfortunately right now your question is vague enough that I feel like you're asking us to read your mind.

Comment: Thanks @DBS and sorry for the vagueness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question makes sense and can illustrate something useful. You want to create a method that is easy to scale up. As mentioned in the comments, you do not want to write a function for each question, that would make it really hard to build a question bank. You want a single function that takes any question with all the information you need. Then the function just needs to read the corresponding info from the question bank. You could add another label, like `pict`. Something like (non-functioning code):

```
const questions = [
{
    question:  `What league do Manchester United play in?`,
    pict: "assets/images/image2.png",
    answers: [
        {text: 'Premier League', correct: true},
        {text: 'Championship', correct: false},
        {text: 'League One', correct: false},
        {text: 'Scottish Premiership', correct: false}
    ]
},
{
    question: 'What league do Millwall play in?',
    pict: "assets/images/image3.png",
    answers: [
        {text: 'Premier League', correct: false},
        {text: 'Championship', correct: true},
        {text: 'League One', correct: false},
        {text: 'Scottish Premiership', correct: false}
    ]
},
...
];

function displayQuestion(q){
  // Choose question
  let i = ... ; //someRandomValue;
  let question = q[i];
  //
  document.getElementById('crest').src = question.pict;
}

displayQuestion(questions);
```